# Carrierwave dropbox check whether the file exists or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dropbox, carrierwave

I am trying to move all images from my local file system to dropbox using carrierwave-dropbox.

I want to check whether the image exists or not.

My console output

```
>Article.first.image?
>true
```

But the dropbox location doesn't have the file and it shows "true" because of following entry in my database.

```
#<ImageUploader:0x007f8574143ee8
@file=
 #<CarrierWave::Storage::Dropbox::File:0x007f8574143308
  @client=
  #<DropboxClient:0x007f8574143420
   @root="dropbox",
   @session=
    #<DropboxSession:0x007f8574143498
    @access_token=#<OAuthToken:0x007f8574143470 @key="123453333",      @secret="22222222222">,
   @consumer_key="abcdeafs",
   @consumer_secret="asdfasfj",
   @locale=nil,
   @request_token=nil>>,
   @config=
{:app_key=>"asdfasfasf",
 :app_secret=>"asdfkasfksf",
 :access_token=>"adfkjasfkhs",
 :access_token_secret=>"aksdfkhsfksf",
 :access_type=>"dropbox",
 :user_id=>"292929292"},
 @path="uploads/images/370/image.png",
 @uploader=#<ImageUploader:0x007f8574143ee8 ...>>,
 @model=
  #Artcle Model>,
  @mounted_as=:image,
  @storage=
  #<CarrierWave::Storage::Dropbox:0x007f8574143c90
   @config=
    {:app_key=>"asdfasfasf",
    :app_secret=>"asdfkasfksf",
    :access_token=>"adfkjasfkhs",
    :access_token_secret=>"aksdfkhsfksf",
    :access_type=>"dropbox",
    :user_id=>"292929292"},
   @dropbox_client=
  #<DropboxClient:0x007f8574143420
   @root="dropbox",
   @session=
    #<DropboxSession:0x007f8574143498
    @access_token=#<OAuthToken:0x007f8574143470 @key="123453333",     @secret="22222222222">,
     @consumer_key="abcdeafs",
     @consumer_secret="asdfasfj",
     @locale=nil,
     @request_token=nil>>,
     @uploader=#<ImageUploader:0x007f8574143ee8 ...>>
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

From reading [the source code](https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/dropbox.rb), it doesn't look like this library has built-in support for testing a file's existence.

Here's some code that **might** work. (I haven't tested it at all, I've never used carrierwave-dropbox, and and I'm not fluent in Ruby.)

```
dropbox_file = Article.first.image
exists = false
begin
    dropbox_file.client.metadata(dropbox_file.path)
    exists = true
rescue DropboxError
end
```

**EDIT**: If you want to be more specific on the error handling, do something like this:

```
rescue DropboxError => e
    if e.http_response.code == '404'
        # the file is not found
    else
        # some other error occurred
    end
end
```